# RestSharp File upload works in v106.15 fails in 107.1.1

Tags: restsharp

I'm uploading a screenshot failure png to Test Rail via their API - Here's the code that works in 106:

```
Request = new RestRequest("/index.php?/api/v2/add_attachment_to_result/85)
.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
.AddFile("attachment", "C:\Source\screenshot.png");

IRestResponse AddAttachmentResponse = Client.Post(Request);
```

The only thing I changed after the upgrade to v107 is the last line:

```
RestResponse AddAttachmentResponse = Client.PostAsync(Request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I now get an error back from the Test Rail API "Bad Request" - here's the documentation on their API: [Test Rail Add Attachment API doc](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/reference/attachments/#addattachmenttoresult) - I know the http engine has changed in 107 - what do I need to do differently now?

UPDATE:
It appears that v107 is not sending the Content-Type in the header - here's the output from HttpTracer:

==================== HTTP ERROR REQUEST: [POST] ====================
Authorization: Basic *TokenRemoved*
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, *+json, application/xml, text/xml, *+xml, *
User-Agent: RestSharp/107.1.1.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cookie: tr_session=7cef485e-1aca-46bb-a773-9d9f5d410ee6
--8eef1c58-a3df-4ddb-a1c5-e081ccf90709
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=attachment; filename=Untitled.png; filename*=utf-8''Untitled.png

snipped for brevity

Note there is a Content-Type in the body, but none in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue link: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1713

As we discussed, `HttpTracer` only shows the request headers, and `Content-Type` is the request header.

When debugging this issue (and a couple of other related issues), we found out that the issue was caused by the server not being able to handle `name` and `filename` parameters in the form part (`Content-Disposition` header) if they are not wrapped in quotes. Strangely enough, adding content disposition directly using `ContentDispositionHeaderValue` doesn't add quotes by default. After adding them manually it started to work:

```
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") {
    Name     = $"\"{file.Name}\"",
    FileName = $"\"{file.FileName}\""
};
```

My answer is for anyone who experienced a similar issue with 107.1, the latest alpha and the next stable version should handle this properly.